# integrating GCM and gcm_defaultSenderId is not resolved

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am integrating **GCM** into my app, what i did was i have made the configuration file **google-services.json** and placed it inside the **app** folder (i am using Android Studio) the **resource** file is also **imported** and I am also including the plugin in my `build.gradle` of application like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the *problem is that it is still not resolved*. I want to know what is wrong?

I have searched about it and i find [this](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/lxW/java-android-android-studio-android-gcm-what-is-authorizedentity-cant-find-gcm-defaultsenderid-in-own-app), i have used my project number now there is no error coming up. Is it right way to do? Someone please explain

Comment: I am not sure if I am right but I assume you are not sure about the purpose of the sender id? Have a look at this https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#senderid, here sender id and the other credentials used for GCM-implementations are explained. 

You have to get the sender id from your GCM-project from the Google Dev Console and use it when calling 'instanceID.getToken("place_your_sender_id_here",
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null)'

Comment: i know the purpose of sender ID what i am asking it should read itself by reading the json config file, isn't it?

Comment: No you have to pass it manually to the register-method. As far as I know the config file is quite useless, I have got two Gcm-projects running fine without even having the config file included.

Comment: I downloaded the sample and there i just added the config file in app folder and it doesn't ask me to add it manually. I don't understand why it is not working in my other project Also if i added it manually will it work perfectly. It is creating the gcm token so i am presuming it is working fine.

Comment: As soon as you receive a token everything is fine of course. We are having a similar discussion on another thread, refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31717800/3863059  As you discovered, you can manually hand over your sender id or, if the plugin would do it´s work, you should be able to use the generated R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId-resource containing your sender id defined in the config file. If the plugin is not working in your own project, I personally would just copy the sample and remove everything you do not need or just keep going with manually passing the sender id

Comment: You can drop the R.string id and get the value by name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38995785/606351

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the gradle files of the official google example: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

You will see you need to do two things:

add

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
```

to project gradle build file and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of module app gradle build file.