# Can I use my existing server type api key for GCM 8.4?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to update to GCM 8.4 from 8.3, but part of the new process requires auto generation of a json file. I tried that with my existing project, but it  created a new api key of type "Android" while the api key I was using before was of type "Server". Is it possible to use my existing "Server" key so that existing users continue getting push notifications? If so how am I supposed to go about doing so?

I can manually edit the json file, but I'm not sure how the old data I was using corresponds. The old information I have is the GCM_PROJECT_ID and a GCM_CLIENT_ID (same as project id except with some sort of hash and has "apps.googleusercontent.com").

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31151775/6124253) where it guides on how to retrieve a **Server** API Key instead of an **Android** type? If so, can you also include in your post the references that you have already checked out, so the community can narrow down to only the untried possible solutions for you. :)

Comment: Thanks. After some searching I found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411787/why-do-i-need-to-add-the-configuration-file-to-my-project-to-setup-gcm-correctly)It seems to suggest I can put in some random configuration file to get past the build errors and just never reference the auto generated string. Not quite sure if I need to use the client id or project id instead though.